# how to use agrona.OneToOneRingBuffer

Tags: java

I just want to test `agrona.OneToOneRingBuffer`. i have one `Producer` to produce message,one `Consumer` to consume.But My consumer class has no output because countdownlatch doesn't zero out.

```
public class Producer implements Runnable{
    private final RingBuffer buffer;

    public Producer(RingBuffer buffer) {

        this.buffer = buffer;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i=0;i<Config.SIZE;i++){
            String s = String.format("i am %s",i);
            System.out.println( "name -> " + s);
            UnsafeBuffer unsafeBuffer = new UnsafeBuffer(s.getBytes());
            unsafeBuffer.wrap(s.getBytes());
            buffer.write(1, unsafeBuffer, 0, s.length());
        }

    }
}

public class Consumer implements Runnable {
    private final RingBuffer buffer;

    public Consumer(RingBuffer buffer) {
        this.buffer = buffer;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(Config.SIZE);
        while (countDownLatch.getCount() > 0) {
            buffer.read((msgTypeId, srcBuffer, index, length) -> {
                byte[] message = new byte[length];
                srcBuffer.getBytes(index, message);
                System.out.println("Consumer <- " + new String(message));
                countDownLatch.countDown();
            });
        }

        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("cost time " + (end - start));
    }
}
public class App {
    private static final OneToOneRingBuffer BUFFER = new OneToOneRingBuffer(new UnsafeBuffer(
            ByteBuffer.allocate(1024 + RingBufferDescriptor.TRAILER_LENGTH)));


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        executor.execute(new Producer(BUFFER));
        executor.execute(new Consumer(BUFFER));

        Thread.currentThread().join();
    }
}
```

The Config.SIZE just set to 100_000 and when it was 10_000 ,the programe runs well.
Is the OneToOneRingBuffer class a thread-unsafe class?